# Webpack JSX error: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, jsx

i'm trying to build the project with webpack, but i get error. I was able to build this project earlier with gulp, so all the paths and everything should be ok. I installed all babel loaders from this documentation https://github.com/babel/babel-loader and copied the code from examples.

```js
ERROR in ./src/app.jsx
Module parse failed: ..path../src/app.jsx Line 1: Unexpected token
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import React from 'react';
| import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
 @ multi main
```

my webpack.config file:

```js
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    devtools: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: [
        './src/app.jsx'
    ],
    output: {
        path: '../app/www/js/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: [path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.scss']
    },
    modules: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `loader: 'babel'`, not `loader: 'babel-loader'`

EDIT: Apparently they're equivalent. The issue is in the Webpack configuration file, it's `module`, not `modules`.

Comment: it was babel initially. When i was looking for solutions i changed this to "babel-loader" to see if this will work. I changed it now back to "babel" and i still get the same error

Comment: `"devDependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.3.14",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",
    "browserify": "^13.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {}`

Comment: ... i'm not used to controls of stackoverflow yet. I pressed "enter" accidently and posted the message. I'm not really bothering with package.json file because i'm not posting this project anywhere. So all the modules installations i do without --save-dev. 

So the rest of the package.json file is just a standard what you get after npm install. That's why i posted only devDependencies

Comment: You don't appear to have `babel-loader` installed. Try doing the `npm install` exactly as specified in the github page you linked. Also, using `package.json` is not just for when you want to publish projects somewhere, it's useful to keep track of your deps (and dev-deps) if you'll ever want to move it on another machine or just push it to a private repo without having to push `node_modules` as well.

Comment: http://imgur.com/VCGxwOh These are all modules i have installed. I have babel-loader

Comment: Got it, you have a typo in your `webpack.config.js`. It's `module`, not `modules`!